# Using CheckBoxes/Buttons from other forms

Tags: c#, winforms

There are 2 different forms.

**Form1** and **Form2**

Form1 has 6 different checkBoxes and one button.

If you press the button, form2 opens and form1 gets closed and and the special buttons get visible, which you checked in the checkboxes before.

There are 6 buttons on form2 but all are set as `visible = false.`

For example: CheckBox 2 and 6 are checked and you press the button.

Form2 opens and Button 2 and 6 are visible.

But I cant use the CheckBoxes and Buttons from the different forms. I already set the Checkboxes and Buttons as public in the designer.

Can anyone help? Sorry for my bad english, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this WPF, Webforms, Winforms, Xamarin, what?

Comment: Windows form-app (.net framework)

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Yes, specify the tech. Second thing - you cannot (or at least should not) pass instances of control objects between different forms -> store the actually clicked checkboxes into some sort of variable (e.g var checkboxArray = new bool[5]) and then pass the array as parameter of contructor while creating the 2nd form - and in constructor, read the array and set desired controls appropiately.

Comment: Please provide some code samples and also screenshots could be beneficial for understanding of the user journey you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Add this **EventHandler** to the `.Click` event of the button on `Form1`:

```
//Click EventHandler for Button on Form1
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Create instance of Form2
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();

    //Check which CheckBoxes are checked
    foreach(CheckBox checkbox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
    {
        if (checkbox.Checked)
        {
            //Get number of Checkbox
            string number = checkbox.Name.Replace("checkBox", string.Empty);

            //Show the corresponding Button on Form2
            Button button = f2.Controls.Find("button" + number, true).FirstOrDefault() as Button;
            button.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    //Show Form2
    f2.Show();

    //Close or hide Form1
    this.Hide();
}
```

**Note:** Keep in mind that for this to work your `CheckBoxes` on `Form1` have to be called:

> checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, ...

and the `Buttons` on `Form2` have to be called:

> button1, button2, button3, ...

you could also add or remove `Buttons` and `CheckBoxes` at any point. Just make sure they're named correctly.

**Unrelated Note:** Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you ask your next question. And welcome to SO! :)

Answer (score 0):

> I already set the Checkboxes and Buttons as public in the designer.

I assume this means you changed the `Modifiers` property of the Buttons on Form2 to Public?

If so, then when you create Form2 from Form1, simply do:

```
// ... from within Form1 ...
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.button1.Visible = this.checkBox1.Checked;
f2.button2.Visible = this.checkBox2.Checked;
f2.button3.Visible = this.checkBox3.Checked;
f2.button4.Visible = this.checkBox4.Checked;
f2.button5.Visible = this.checkBox5.Checked;
f2.button6.Visible = this.checkBox6.Checked;
f2.Show();
```

As Klemikaze mentioned in the comments, a more correct approach would be to pass the states to an overloaded Form2 constructor:

```
// ... in Form1 ...
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool[] checkStates = new bool[] {
        checkBox1.Checked, checkBox2.Checked, checkBox3.Checked,
        checkBox4.Checked, checkBox5.Checked, checkBox6.Checked
    };
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(checkStates);            
    f2.Show();
}
```

Then in Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(bool[] btnVisibleStates)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for(int i=0; i<btnVisibleStates.Length; i++)
        {
            String btnName = "button" + (i + 1);
            Button btn = this.Controls.Find(btnName, true).FirstOrDefault() as Button;
            if (btn != null)
            {
                btn.Visible = btnVisibleStates[i];
            }
        }
    }

}
```